# No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: asp.net, excel

Hi i am trying to update a excel file using the oledb connections. But i am getting the following error:
    "No value given for one or more required parameters."
This is my code:

```
String sConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"TempUploads\" + hdnExcelName.Value) + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=NO'";
    OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
    objConn.Open();
    string sql = "update [Sheet1$] set [A8]='apple1.jpg'";
    OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(sql, objConn);
    objCmdSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
    objConn.Close();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HDR=No, the various columns are referred to as F1, F2, F3 etc. A8 is not suitable.

The SQL should be on the lines of:

```
UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET F1='apple1.jpg' 
WHERE F2='Blah'
```

EDIT re comment

```
strSQL = "SELECT f1 From [Sheet1$a8:a8]"
```

Comment: hi remou thanks a ton for replying to my question. I need to update the records in a particular row but i am not having any primary key column. is there a way to update a particular row on the basis of row number in excel???

Comment: You can create a single cell recordset, I have added a note.